# switsh and helpSwitch methods missing from org.refcodes.console.ConsoleSugar when upgrading to 2.x

Tags: java, scala, maven, console

I was using org.refcode.refcodes-console version 1.1.9. When upgrading to 2.0.4, it seems various methods no longer exist.

My scala code:

```
val theHelp =  helpSwitch("Shows this help")
```

I get this error when compiling: `not found: value helpSwitch`

Same error when using `switsh` and `StringOptionImpl`.

How should I replace them when migrating from 1.x to 2.x for this maven artifact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 'switch' (aka switsh) methods in ConsoleSugar have been renamed to 'flag' in major version 2. So 'switsh' has been renamed to 'flag' and 'helpSwitch' has been renamed to 'helpFlag'.
For StringOptionImpl, use 'SpringOption' instead.

So in the example provided, it should now be:

```
val theHelp =  helpFlag("Shows this help")
```

Also, for the switsh method you would need to add a 'aAlias' parameter as the third parameter. For example:

```
val block = switsh("-w", "--wait", "Wait at the end of the Program")
```

would need to be something like become

```
val block = flag("-w", "--wait", "wait", "Wait at the end of the Program")
```